# Subtract a number of days from given date (from scratch) in C++

Tags: c++, date, time, addition, subtraction

I have a function below used to add a number of days to a given date (format: yyyy/mm/dd addDays). It does not work for leap years (there was a rushed failed attempt to make leap years work.) How can I edit this so I may subtract days from a given date? I imagine I will need a for loop which also subtracts days from addDays_ but with a decrement and  reset. I'd also like to make it calculate leap year dates successfully.

```
int year;
int month;
int day;
int changeDays;

void DaysToDate::add(int addDays_) {
    //Calculate the date add the changeDays.
    // Do NOT input values greater than 730 days.

    int monthdays[] = { 0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31 };
    int daysInYear = 365;
    
    if (isLeapYear(year) || isLeapYear(year+1) == true) {
        monthdays[2] = 29;
        daysInYear = 366;
        
    }

    if (addDays_ >= daysInYear) {
        int addyears = addDays_ / daysInYear;
        year += addyears;

        if (isLeapYear(year) == true) {
            
            monthdays[2] = 29;
            daysInYear = 366;
        }
    }


    int currentDays = day;
    int i = month;
    if (addDays_ >= monthdays[month]) {
        while (addDays_ >= monthdays[i]) {

            if (i + 1 >= 12) {
                month = 1;
                i = 1;
            }
            else 
                month++;

            addDays_ -= monthdays[i];

            //cout << "monthdays[i] "<< monthdays[i] << "\n";
            if (addDays_ + day < monthdays[month]) {
                day += addDays_;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (addDays_ + day < monthdays[month]) {
        day += addDays_;
    }
    if ((day == monthdays[month - 1]) && (month < 12))
    {
        day = 1;
        month++;
    }
    if ((day == monthdays[month - 1]) && (month == 12))
    {
        day = 1;
        month = 1;
        year++;
    }
    else {
        
    }

    cout << year << " " << month << " " << day << " " << "\n";

}

bool DaysToDate::isLeapYear(int year_) {
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

Input `2009/04/05 7` - output `2009 4 12`

Comment: Perhaps these algorithms would help: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Answer (score 1):

For fixing the code to work on leap years:

```
#include <iostream>

int year = 2009;
int month = 02;
int day = 1;
int changeDays;

enum Months
{
    None,
    January,
    February,
    March,
    April,
    May,
    June,
    July,
    August,
    September,
    October,
    November,
    December
};

bool isLeapYear(int year_)
{
    if (year % 400 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (year % 100 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void add(int addDays_)
{
    // Calculate the date add the changeDays.
    //  Do NOT input values greater than 730 days.

    int monthdays[] = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int daysInYear = 365;

    if (isLeapYear(year))
    {
        monthdays[Months::February] = 29;
        daysInYear = 366;
    }

    int currentDays = day;
    int i = month;

    while (addDays_ >= monthdays[i])
    {
        addDays_ -= monthdays[i];
        
        if (i + 1 > Months::December)
        {
            i = Months::January;
            year++;
            if (isLeapYear(year))
            {
                monthdays[Months::February] = 29;
                daysInYear = 366;
            } else {
                monthdays[Months::February] = 28;
                daysInYear = 365;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
    month = i;

    if (addDays_ + day <= monthdays[month])
    {
        day += addDays_;
    }
    else if (month < Months::December) {
        addDays_ -= monthdays[month] - day;
        day = addDays_;
        month++;
    } else {
        addDays_ -= monthdays[month] - day;
        day = addDays_;
        month = Months::January;
        year ++;
        if (isLeapYear(year))
        {
            monthdays[Months::February] = 29;
            daysInYear = 366;
        } else {
            monthdays[Months::February] = 28;
            daysInYear = 365;
        }
    }

    std::cout << year << " " << month << " " << day << " "
         << "\n";
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    add(7);
    add(365);
    add(365);
    add(365);
    add(365);
    return 0;
}
```

Surely some improvements can be done to my suggestion but I think it is easy to follow, as it has a very similar structure to yours.

As a general tip, you had a lot of redundant if statements and some of them would cause errors, such as

```
if (isLeapYear(year) || isLeapYear(year+1) == true) {
    monthdays[2] = 29;
    daysInYear = 366;  
}
```

checking isLeapYear(year+1) will get you a wrong number of days if you start before march

Comment: Thank you for reading that part too, I opted to add an additional function so that the redundancy could be reduced

Answer (score 1):

You could use ranges for this. The operation of adding (or subtracting) a number of days `n` to a given date `ymd` may be then thought as:

- Generate a view of the current date `ymd` plus the following dates (a maximum of 730).
- From that view, drop the first `n` elements.
- Then take the first element of the remaining.

The `ranges::views::generate_n` code will contain the logic for adding (or subtracting) a day to a given date:

- This logic will make use of the `days_per_month` function.
- The `days_per_month` function will make use of the `is_leap_year` function.

The code below:

- Defines a struct `ymd` to hold the values of a given date.
- Implements the addition and subtraction of days to a given date as non member operators of the struct `ymd`.
- Uses Eric Niebler's [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library for the range operations.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/KdWTTTr7q)

```cpp
#include <cassert>  // assert
#include <iomanip>  // setw
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct ymd {
    int year{};
    int month{};
    int day{};
};

auto is_leap_year(int y) {
    return (y % 4 == 0) and ((y % 100 != 0) or (y % 400 == 0));
}

auto days_per_month(int y, int m) {
    static int dpm[] = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if (m == 2 and is_leap_year(y)) { return 29; }
    else { return dpm[m]; }
}

auto operator+(const ymd& d, int days_to_add) {
    static const int max_days_to_add{730};
    assert(days_to_add <= max_days_to_add);
    auto ret_v =
        ranges::views::generate_n([dd=d]() mutable -> ymd {
            auto tmp{dd};
            dd.day += 1;
            if (dd.day > days_per_month(dd.year, dd.month)) { dd.day = 1; dd.month += 1; }
            if (dd.month > 12) { dd.month = 1; dd.year += 1; }
            return tmp;
        }, max_days_to_add + 1)
        | ranges::views::drop(days_to_add)
        | ranges::views::take(1)
        | ranges::to<std::vector>();
    return ret_v[0];
}

auto operator+(int days_to_add, const ymd& d) {
    return d + days_to_add;
}

auto operator-(const ymd& d, int days_to_subtract) {
    static const int max_days_to_subtract{730};
    assert(days_to_subtract <= max_days_to_subtract);
    auto ret_v =
        ranges::views::generate_n([dd=d]() mutable -> ymd {
            auto tmp{dd};
            dd.day -= 1;
            if (dd.day < 1) {
                dd.month -= 1;
                if (dd.month < 1) { dd.month = 12; dd.year -= 1; }
                dd.day = days_per_month(dd.year, dd.month);
            }
            return tmp;
        }, max_days_to_subtract + 1)
        | ranges::views::drop(days_to_subtract)
        | ranges::views::take(1)
        | ranges::to<std::vector>();
    return ret_v[0];
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ymd& d) {
    return os << fmt::format("{:04d}/{:02d}/{:02d}", d.year, d.month, d.day);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<ymd,int>> input{
        {{2009,4,5}, 7},
        {{2009,4,5}, 730},
        {{2020,2,20}, 30}
    };
    for (const auto& [d, number_of_days] : input){
        auto dd{ d + number_of_days };
        std::cout << d << " + " << std::setw(3) << number_of_days << " = " << dd << ",\t";
        std::cout << dd << " - " << std::setw(3) << number_of_days << " = " << dd - number_of_days << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//   2009/04/05 +   7 = 2009/04/12, 2009/04/12 -   7 = 2009/04/05
//   2009/04/05 + 730 = 2011/04/05, 2011/04/05 - 730 = 2009/04/05
//   2020/02/20 +  30 = 2020/03/21, 2020/03/21 -  30 = 2020/02/20
```

---

Another, probably simpler, solution would be to loop until you consume the days you want to add, incrementing the current day whether until the beginning of the next month or until you run out of days to add (or decrementing until the end of the previous month if you are subtracting). Again, I would make use of `daysPerMonth` and `isLeapYear` helper functions:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Ka5v7sG8q)

```cpp
    void add(int addDays) {
        static int maxAddDays = 730;
        assert(addDays <= maxAddDays);

        while (addDays) {
            auto current_month_days(daysPerMonth(year_, month_));
            auto tmpAddDays = std::min(addDays, current_month_days - day_ + 1);
            day_ += tmpAddDays;
            addDays -= tmpAddDays;
            if (day_ == current_month_days + 1) { day_ = 1; month_++; }
            if (month_ == 13) { month_ = 1; year_++; }
        }
    }

    void subtract(int subtractDays) {
        static int maxSubtractDays = 730;
        assert(subtractDays <= maxSubtractDays);

        while (subtractDays) {
            auto tmpSubtractDays = std::min(subtractDays, day_);
            day_ -= tmpSubtractDays;
            subtractDays -= tmpSubtractDays;
            if (day_ == 0) {
                month_--;
                if (month_ == 0) { month_ = 12; year_--; }
                day_ = daysPerMonth(year_, month_);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't know about the range library, so I was aiming to emulate a similar function, I could append the description with that information

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to work with dates I recommend you though Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)